# What are the dangers of melting HDPE and silicone? Is it even possible?

Tags: polymers, toxicity, green-chemistry

I've searched the internet and couldn't find a specific answer.
There doesn't seem to be a single recycling company that takes empty silicone tubes (also know as mastic tubes) and recycles them. As a result, here in the UK it goes to landfill. Such a shame and doesn't seem right!

The tube is made from HDPE but is contaminated with the silicone inside it, usually used for sealing windows or bathrooms.

There is a chemical solution available that will strip out the silicone by dissolving it but that doesn't make commercial sense for two reasons;

1. The cost and time involved
2. You are left with a chemical to dispose of

Nobody wants these tubes and it has begun to annoy me!

I'm wondering if anyone could advise of the possibility / dangers of simply melting the empty tubes which result in a plastic mix of HDPE and silicone?

Would it work? Could it work?

Comment: It's not really possible to answer your question since there are many kinds of silicone. For instance, some contain biocides and some others don't. And without even taking into account the commercial stickers or the inks on it. Concerning specifically HDPE plastic, there is a [question and an answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115002/does-melting-hdpe-plastic-produce-toxic-fumes-melting-not-burning) about it.